# Find changing piece of string from a whole text

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, parsing, substring

I need to find a piece of string from a whole text. I know what the piece of text starts with and I know what it possibly ends with. To draw an example here, I'll show you a similar string as what I'm searching for.

aaot:1980

1. (Aaot:) That part always stays there no matter what.
2. (198) These three (there can be more/less digits there) always change.
3. (0, the ending digit) This part does change but it's always 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 9, 0. The same happens to the digits before the last digit.

My theory is to have the program check the digits after the first part, that never changes and the search for the last digit, and then find the digits between them. I'm not sure if it's possible but that's my theory.

I could also just make the program loop throught the digits and wait until it finds the matching digit. That would work by just trying like this aaoa:1, text doesnr contain aaoa:1, try aaoa:2, it matches. Then try the other digits in the same way. This is a much slower way though.

NB! There most likely are multiple strings like this in one text. I need to get thw whole piece of string not just digits.

Comment: Is aaoa: also possible or its that a typo? Can I sum this up as return the numbers that follow colons?

Answer (score 0):

Just use SubString and adjust the length according to how long the string is:

```
Dim s As String = "Aaot:1980"
Dim i As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(s.SubString(5, s.Length - 6), i) Then
    Msgbox("The number in the string is " & i.ToString)
Else
    MsgBox("Number could not be parsed")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the function. But there's still a problem. How do I find the integer if the string is something like this "asdgf gfdgfd aaot:1980" Edit: or this "jjas jfgfd aaot:1927 lkoam aaot:1954"

Comment: "Aaot: That part always stays there no matter what." - so it doesn't then?

Comment: It does, it's just in a text. The part never changes.

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking for numbers that follow colons, then this will return a list of those numbers.

```
Private Function GetDoubles(Text As String) As List(Of Double)
    Dim parts() As String = Split(Text, ":")
    Dim results As New List(Of Double)
    For i As Integer = 1 To parts.Count Step 2 'Odd numbered elements will start with numbers
        results.Add(Val(parts(i))) 'Val function processes only the characters that can be part of a number and ignores the rest.
    Next
    Return results
End Function
```

If the numbers are always integers, then this code will work:

```
Private Function GetIntegers(Text As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim parts() As String = Split(Text, ":")
    Dim results As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To parts.Count Step 2 'Odd numbered elements will start with numbers
        results.Add(CInt(Val(parts(i)))) 'Val function processes only the characters that can be part of a number and ignores the rest.
    Next
    Return results
End Function
```